# Count average value of each key type in MySql

Tags: mysql

i hv a table saving records like this

```
a, 5
a, 6
a, 7
a, 8
b, 1
b, 2
b, 3
c, 1
c, 2
c, 3
c, 4
c, 5
```

---

i want average for each key ->

```
a, (5+6+7+8)/4 = 6.5
b, ..
c, ..
```

---

Any hints?

Comment: this is too broad please have a look at `avg` function of mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let column item and value, so your table like this

item,value
a, 5
a, 6
a, 7
a, 8
b, 1
b, 2
b, 3
c, 1
c, 2
c, 3
c, 4
c, 5

SELECT item,AVG(VALUE) as avg FROM Test.Testing GROUP BY item;

item ,avg
a, 7.2500
b, 2.0000
c, 2.5000
```

Comment: thanks for your help! cant imaging group by is useful here.